# SharePoint Mobile App

Tags: app, mobile

When I post news to my company's SharePoint site, how come I get a notifications in the mobile app, but my Sales person doesn't?  He turned on his push notifications and follows the page.  We want notifications to go to our sales force when we post news because they don't have their laptops readily available all the time and mobile is key.

Answer (score 0):

Users receive news notifications based on relevancy. Unfortunately, we do not control the algorithm that determines the relevancy of news to individual users. You can find out more information here:

[Control notifications in the SharePoint mobile app](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/notifications)